# Unable to resolve superclass of FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Asking again because no answer at the previous topic...
I`m trying to use FragmentPagerAdapter but when trying to run it- there is an error:

> 02-22 22:48:53.328: W/dalvikvm(830): Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Linfo/androidhive/tabsswipe/SlideActivity$FragmentPagerAdapter; (94)
>   02-22 22:48:53.328: W/dalvikvm(830): Link of class
>   'Linfo/androidhive/tabsswipe/SlideActivity$FragmentPagerAdapter;'
>   failed 02-22 22:48:53.328: E/dalvikvm(830): Could not find class
>   'info.androidhive.tabsswipe.SlideActivity$FragmentPagerAdapter',
>   referenced from method
>   info.androidhive.tabsswipe.SlideActivity.onCreate

my code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;


import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.SlideFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;


private ViewPager mPager;


private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu); 

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);


    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.string.action_finish
                    : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


        case R.id.action_previous:

            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:

            // will do nothing.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SlideFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

already tried to build path, clean and import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FragmentPagerAdapter - unable to resolve superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961762/fragmentpageradapter-unable-to-resolve-superclass)

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong imports :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

and

```
mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

should be

```
mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

You can have a look at the docs in `FragmentActivity` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html).

Comment: new errors appeared: The constructor FragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined, The return type is incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int), Type mismatch: cannot convert from SlideFragment to Fragment

Comment: Did you check that SlideFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment ? Types have to be compatible, if you start using the support library, you have to use it everywhere ...

Comment: About the Fragment Pager adapter constructor, it exists : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) so you are probably still using a wrong import somewhere. The rest of the errors will be hard to debug if I don't know what part of the code is causing the issue ...